# html different page content depending on what was clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a site where multiple products will be sold. so far my listing page looks something like this

```
<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
    <div class="features_items"><!--features_items-->
        <h2 class="title text-center">My Products</h2>

        <?php
        $servername = "server";
        $username = "user";
        $password = "pass";
        $dbname = "dbname";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }


        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM myproducts WHERE 1 ORDER BY ProductName ASC";
        $myresult = $conn->query($sql2);

        $x = 1;
        while ($row = $myresult->fetch_assoc()) {
       ?>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="product-image-wrapper">
               <div class="single-products">
                   <div class="productinfo text-center">

                       <img src="../../images/myImages/<?php echo $row['ProductImage1'];?>_0001_1.jpg" alt="../../images/myImages/<?php echo $row['ProductImage1'];?>_0001_1.jpg" />
                       <h2><?php echo $row['ProductPrice']; ?></h2>
                       <p><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></p>
                       <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="product-overlay">
                       <div class="overlay-content">
                           <h2><?php echo $row['Vendor']; ?></h2>
                           <h2><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></h2>
                           <p>$ <?php echo $row['ProductPrice']; ?></p>
                           <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="choose">
                   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <?php
       }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

The code above loops through all the contents in the database and displays them on the screen. What i want is when you click on a product it goes to a different page and displays specific product information. I have hundreds of products to be individually displayed, i want to know if there is a way where i don't have to write 100+ html files, just so each page can have its individual display.

Ideally the setup would be something like the above where it pulls from the db using php and displays what it needs to be displayed on the screen. But my question is once a product is clicked how will the new page know what product has been passed, the only way i can think of that is creating all individual product pages.

Comment: one word: templates.

Comment: What is the unique identifier for a product?  It would seem like whatever link you build per record would incorporate that identifier so it would know what information to retrieve to then display to the user.

Comment: Won't need to do this in JavaScript or jQuery. Write one PHP Page that you can pass the product ID to, and that page can then collect all the Product details and show them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define routes like this

```
my-website.com/product.php?id=2
```

where `id` will be the each product's id.

or

if you have a `slug` column on your table you can do

```
my-website.com/product.php?slug=a-nice-product
```

`slug` will be the stored slug generated for each product.

So whichever works for you, You can then use the product's `id` or `slug` to fetch a particular product for display on the product-details page.

The display format will be based on a predefined template.
Something similar to what you did for the product's listing will be

```
    <?php
  $servername = "server";
  $username = "user";
  $password = "pass";
  $dbname = "dbname";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $id = $_GET['id']; // in the case of "my-website.com/product.php?id=2"

  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM myproducts WHERE id=$id ORDER BY ProductName ASC"; // NOTE:: This is a bad practice
  $myresult = $conn->query($sql2);

  if($myresult):
?>

<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
        <h2 class="title text-center">Details about <?= $myresult['ProductName']; ?></h2>

        <!-- LIST PRODUCT DETAILS BASED ON TEMPLATE DESIGN -->

</div>
<?php
    endif;
    $conn->close();
?>
```

**Updated:**

```
    $id = $_GET['id']; // in the case of "my-website.com/product.php?id=2"

      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM myproducts WHERE id=$id ORDER BY ProductName ASC";
// NOTE:: This is a bad practice as it is open to SQL injection attacks.
```

Read more about [SQL injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)

Again, a cleaner url will look like this

```
my-website.com/product/2
```

or

```
my-website.com/product/a-nice-product
```

But to achieve this you'll need to setup some htaccess rules.

Comment: Although the answer is detailed, but please note that: 1- Answer should not have included the URL part as it may confuse. 2- If something is not a good practice, then it is not supposed to be added in the answer. Or, at least, explain why it is a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you @MohammedAkhtarZuberi